# Kotlin - How do I do an indexed accessor for member field?

Tags: kotlin

I want to be able to access one of an object's member fields using [x, y] notation, such as board.tiles[0, 0] = 42. Is that possible?

Here's an idea of what I'm trying to do....

***DOES NOT COMPILE***

```
class Tile(var value: Int = 0){

}

class Board() {
    var _tiles = Array<Tile>(100) {Tile()} //Represents a 10x10 playing board

    var tiles
    get(x: Int, y: Int) {return _tiles[y * 10 + x]}
    set(x:Int, y: Int, value: Tile) {_tiles[y * 10 + x] = value}

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val board = Board()
    board.tiles[0,0].value = 42
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get that syntax, you'll need to overload the [indexing operators](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#indexed), for example like this:

```
class Board() {

    private var _tiles = Array<Tile>(100) { Tile() } //Represents a 10x10 playing board

    operator fun get(x: Int, y: Int): Tile {
        return _tiles[y * 10 + x]
    }

    operator fun set(x: Int, y: Int, value: Tile) {
        _tiles[y * 10 + x] = value
    }

}
```

This would give you the following syntax:

```
val board = Board()
board[0, 0].value = 42
println(board[0, 0])
```

If you specifically want to do `board.tiles[0, 0]`, you'll have to nest a property inside `Board` with those operator overloads.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin defines some conventions that let you do things as suggested. Have a look at [Indexed access `operator`s](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#indexed).

```
class Board {
    var tiles = Array(100) { Tile() } //Represents a 10x10 playing board

    operator fun get(x: Int, y: Int) = tiles[y * 10 + x]

    operator fun set(x: Int, y: Int, value: Tile) {
        tiles[y * 10 + x] = value
    }

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val board = Board()
    board[0, 0].value = 42
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact you can have have something like this:

```
val t: Tile = Tile(0)
val tiles = Array(10) { Array<Tile>(10) { t } } // for initialization 
tiles[0][0] = Tile(5)
tiles[0][1] = Tile(7)
....................
```